# Reformat user input of phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to allow user to enter phone number which must start with country code.
So it can be only **+41... or 0041...** (41 is just example not fixed).
If user enter **41 555 666** that is invalid number.
Now, user can also enter **+41/555-666** as I don't want this other characters I want to remove them to get only **+41555666** which I did with code bellow.

As I want to make things simpler I wan't to prevent and **+** and replace it with **00** so if user enter **+41 88/555-666** it code should fix this to **004188555666** I think it's easier.

But I am stuck I can't replace that **+** with **00** so I need a little help as this will maybe require and `regex` and I don't know that :( very good.

```
<input type="text" id="txt" onblur="
var t = document.getElementById('txt').value; 
if(t.charAt(0) == '+'){t = t.replaceAt(0, '00');}
t = t.replace(/\D/g,'');document.getElementById('txt').value = t;"/>
```

Comment: It would be best to account for any possible user input that would be acceptable. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the phone number format from your example, but this should be correct.

```
var phone = '+41/555-666';

var phone = phone.match(/\+?(\d{2})[^\d]?(\d{3})[^\d]?(\d{3})/);

//now you can format the phone number however you want!
var formatted = '00'+phone[1]+phone[2]+phone[3];

console.log(formatted);
```

This is what the regex looks like if passed as a variable - which is nice for breaking it up and commenting it.

```
var regex = new RegExp(
  '\\+?'+ //optional "+"
  '(\\d{2})'+ //capture 2 digits
  '[^\\d]?'+ //optional character that isn't a digit
  '(\\d{3})'+ //capture 3 digits
  '[^\\d]?'+ //optional character that isn't a digit
  '(\\d{3})' //capture 3 digits
);
```

#### Update: Here is the solution that will deal with the above scenario AND the optional second set of digits.

```
var phone = '+41 88/555-666';

var regex = new RegExp(
  '\\+?'+ //optional "+"
  '(\\d{2})'+ //capture 2 digits
  '[^\\d]?'+ //optional character that isn't a digit
  '(\\d{2})?'+ //capture 2 optional digits
  '[^\\d]?'+ //optional character that isn't a digit
  '(\\d{3})'+ //capture 3 digits
  '[^\\d]?'+ //optional character that isn't a digit
  '(\\d{3})' //capture 3 digits
);

var phone = phone.match(regex);

for (var k in phone) {
  //filter out the optional digit capture group if they don't exist
  if (phone[k] === undefined) { phone[k] = ''; }
}

//now you can format the phone number however you want!
var formatted = '00'+phone[1]+phone[2]+phone[3]+phone[4];

console.log(formatted);
```

#### This is for the format of phone numbers I am used to here in the US.

I'm including this in case it helps someone else looking at this post.

```
//some samples
var phone = '100-555-1234';
//var phone = '1234567890';
//var phone = '556.555.1234';

var phone = phone.match(/(\d{3})[^\d]?(\d{3})[^\d]?(\d{4})/);

var formatted = '('+phone[1]+') '+phone[2]+'-'+phone[3];

console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: Sorry just a subquestion if I enter '+41 66 343 12 98' It gives me '0041663431' - not whole number?

Comment: @1110 hmm.. the format of your numbers is strange to me. I was using the first example you gave of `'+41/555-666'`. With `+41 88/555-666` what is `88`? That is also optional, then? I don't know what that means, but the logic is easy. I'll update my answer again.

Comment: @1110 ok, answer updated. The best thing to do is learn from these examples and be able to adapt the regex yourself. My comments on them should help. Just know that the `/  /` at the beginning and end are only used in the non-commented version and in the commented version, all `\` must be doubled. The one liner is easier because it has less `\`, but the commented one helps because it is broken up. Just examine each one and try to understand what it does. This link will help you get started. http://regexone.com/

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
t=t.replace(/\+/,"00");
```